# They have found, or they have been finding?

Tags: present-perfect

> In Beijing, China, researchers at the Wuhan University have been taking a closer look at the thick bone that cushions the woodpecker's brain. They have been comparing the skull structure of great spotted woodpeckers to other birds.
>
> They **have been finding** that small adaptations in the structure of the bones, a micro-structure, acts as a protective armor to the brain. "The wood pecker's brain is surrounded by thick, plate-like spongy bone. At a microscopic level, woodpeckers have a mesh-like structure in the bone that makes up a spongy bone plate.  This mesh is closer together in the woodpecker than in the skylark." For this reason, the researchers are suggesting that this micro-structure gives the woodpecker a better "helmet".

It is said that they **have been finding** because it is "ongoing activity relates to past research". But why is it ongoing activity, they **have found** and all, haven't they?

Comment: You could in this instance just as correctly use *they have found*. But as you have noted *they have been finding* suggests either that the research is ongoing, or that these discoveries are in some way incidental to some other ongoing work. I don't know why it is ongoing, but the wording certainly seems to suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe "have been finding" indicates that action started in the past and continues (or effects of this action continue) into the present. "Have found" indicates the action has been fully completed in the past.

This may be an ongoing activity if they are still "finding" or observing these adaptations, i.e. their research has yet to cease.